# os x 10.6.8 sudden wi-fi problems (no recent upgrade)

Tags: macos, wireless-networking, connection, macbook-pro

MacBook pro, os x 10.6.8 for many months. No recent OS changes. Connected easily @ home & different location this morning. Suddenly no connection @ 3rd location. Back home now, connected on different laptop to same router that won't talk to the MacBook Pro.

Tried resetting PRAM from another trouble shooting list. Only change is that now the wi-fi icon shows "!" on top of grey bars instead of all black bars as it did before PRAM procedure. Now what?

Comment: When clicking that icon, what message do you see? (And maybe you get some more details when holding down Option when clicking.)

Answer (score 1):

http://support.apple.com/kb/HT3821 has descriptions of the Wi-Fi menu extra icons:

> **Connection Warning**
>
> [image]
>
> If the AirPort has a self-assigned IP address, a connection warning will appear. This icon will only show a warning if the interface is configured for DHCP but it doesn't get a lease, and no other interface is correctly configured.

Other things to try:

- Renew the DHCP lease from System Preferences > Network > Wi-Fi > Advanced > TCP/IP.
- Search for the status message shown in System Preferences > Network > Wi-Fi or any messages shown when you option-click the Wi-Fi icon.
- Run `en=$(networksetup -listallhardwareports | awk '/^Hardware Port: (Wi-Fi|AirPort)$/{getline;print $2}'); sudo ifconfig $en down; sudo ifconfig $en up`.

Related questions:

- [How do I troubleshoot my Wi-Fi connection when an exclamation mark appears?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/49082/how-do-i-troubleshoot-my-wi-fi-connection-when-an-exclamation-mark-appears)

Comment: Tks for the things to look for; have saved to file. Yay! Don't need them today. Yet. "!" gone, connection working. Guess giving the laptop a good night's sleep worked in this case. (as in "Sleep it off; call me in the morning....") As noted, will save your steps to pursue if needed.